# Load data into MultiIndex Data Frame from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161926/pandas-data-frame-from-dictionary) is very similar to mine, but in my case, I would like to have each sample introduced as a row of the DataFrame.

From this:

```
sample={'user1': {'item11': 2.5, 'item12': 3.5, 'item13': 3.0}, 
'user2': {'item21': 2.5}, 
'user3': {'item31':4.5,'item32':1.0}}
```

How can I get this?

```
    user1                user2  user3
    item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0   2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0
```

And then, when getting a new sample like this one:

```
sample1={'user1': {'item11': 4.5, 'item12': 5.5, 'item13': 1.0}, 
'user2': {'item21': 4.5}, 
'user3': {'item31':5.5,'item32':3.0}}
```

How can it be introduced to get:

```
    user1                user2  user3
    item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0   2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0   
1   4.5    5.5    1.0    4.5    5.5    3.0
```

Note  that each sample has always same users and each user has always same items. For example user3 always has item31 and item32.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)

You can feed your nested dictionary to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor, `stack`, swap index levels, convert to a dataframe, and finally transpose.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sample).stack().swaplevel().to_frame().T

print(df)

   user1                user2  user3       
  item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0    2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0
```

Then to append data from a new dictionary `sample1`:

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(sample1).stack().swaplevel().to_frame().T)
```

If appending to your dataframe row by row is not in itself a requirement, I strongly advise you restructure your logic to construct your dataframe in one call after collecting *all* your input data. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) include a relevant example with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat).

Answer (score 3):

Use nested dict comprehension with [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) with list of samples for better performance:

```
sample={'user1': {'item11': 2.5, 'item12': 3.5, 'item13': 3.0}, 
'user2': {'item21': 2.5}, 
'user3': {'item31':4.5,'item32':1.0}}

sample1={'user1': {'item11': 4.5, 'item12': 5.5, 'item13': 1.0}, 
'user2': {'item21': 4.5}, 
'user3': {'item31':5.5,'item32':3.0}}

samples = [sample, sample1]

L = [{(k, k1): v1 for k, v in s.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()} for s in samples]

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(set(y for x in L for y in x.keys()))
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = mux).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   user1                user2  user3       
  item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0    2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0
1    4.5    5.5    1.0    4.5    5.5    3.0
```

If not possible, create each DataFrame separately and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = {(k, k1): v1 for k, v in sample.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(L, index=[0])

L1 = {(k, k1): v1 for k, v in sample1.items() for k1, v1 in v.items()}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L1, index=[0])

df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
print (df)

   user1                user2  user3       
  item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0    2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0
1    4.5    5.5    1.0    4.5    5.5    3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with `pd.concat` + `DataFrame.from_dict()` and lastly transpose :

```
>>> pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, 'index') for k, v in sample.items()}, axis=0).T
   user1                user2  user3
  item11 item12 item13 item21 item31 item32
0    2.5    3.5    3.0    2.5    4.5    1.0
```

OR

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, orient='index') for k, v in sample.items()}).T  # you can chosse `orient` to have index
```

Comment: Nice. Note `axis=0` is the default so not strictly required.